# What way would you keep track on already seen content?

Tags: javascript, database, algorithm, web, backend

Let's say we have some site where you can post your photos, subscribe to other users. There is an endpoint like `/feed` where you see photos of people you're subscribed on and there the site should hide what you have already seen.

I have been thinking about ways to keep track on what have been already seen and almost the only thing I came up with is organizing many-to-many relationship between, let's say, `User` and `Photos` and 3rd table would save `user_id` and `photo_id` for every single entry and every single entry means that user with such a `user_id` read the post with a `post_id` so now I can filter what was seen.

Another way I came up with is saving id of just seen post in localStorage which seems a wrong way...

So, are there better ways than the first one I thought of? What way would you do this if this differs from what I suggested?

Also, if we need also consider "likes", is it a good idea to make one more field for the 3rd table - `is_liked` (because logically thinking, liked photo should be considered as seen)

Comment: I guess you'd have a `/allpost`-like endpoint, just add a flag to indicate which have been read and It would be fine.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context, though.

Comment: @appleapple I'm not sure about flag as there are multiple users. What way are you suggesting to save unique list of seen posts for every single user?

Comment: so the site currently cannot re-read post?

Comment: @appleapple it can, just that when we go to `/feed` we should be able somehow tell what posts have been already seen either hiding them completely or putting, let's say, a special icon. What I'm asking is what ways would you keep that for every unique user, maybe in database (if so then what way exactly), maybe some other way

Comment: since you can re-read per-person post, there would have been the related per-person storage, I don't see why adding a flag is hard.

Comment: @appleapple what kind of storage it would be? if database then what kind of structure you suggest to use? consider that there can be over 1 million seen posts for many users

Comment: the storage you use to store per-person post, sure.

Comment: @appleapple there is no per-person post store, there is only one global table with all posts and every single entry there has a field with id of user to connect Posts table with Users table (one to many relationship). If I add a flag `is_seen` to Posts table then we won't be able to differ what users already seen this post so I'm asking you what kind of structure you're suggesting

Comment: I don't get it, you can (re-)read per-person post, but there is no related storage?

Comment: @appleapple how is rereading posts related to having a storage?

Comment: because the data need to be store somewhere.

Comment: @appleapple if I simplify this we have two stores: all posts (Posts tabgle) and all users (Users table). What else we need to have to keep track on already seen posts is the question

Comment: OK, so this site still *cannot* re-read posts. the problem is not only -- how to **hide** already seem post --